# Common Lisp grab stdout in real time

Tags: common-lisp

I'm trying to read stdout from functions I call and can't seem to get it to work in real time.

```
(defun foo ()
    (loop :for i :from 1 :to 3 :do
          (format T "~A~%" i)
          (sleep 1)))

(let* ((s (make-string-output-stream))
       (*standard-output* s))
    (foo)
    ...)
```

will capture the output and make it available after the function is done. How can I get the output before that? I looked through swank's source and they seem to have some sort of events set up, but I can't figure out how they're hooking into stdout.

Comment: You can't possibly do this without some kind of multithreading or coroutines or something like that, since whatever reads the output from `foo` must run interleaved / concurrently with it.

Comment: Also ... Why not just capture the function output directly? Why do it via stdout?

Comment: so far, it seems threads with a custom stream to synchronize it is the way to go. doesn't appear to be a way with standard features to do it. I need to do it via stdout because I want to capture the output of things like compile-file, which only print to the standard streams.

Comment: BTW, you can use `(with-output-to-string (*standard-output*) (foo) ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As should be obvious it is not possible to have code which runs concurrently with other code in the CL language defined by the standard, since to do this inherently requires multiple threads of control (what is meant to be listening to any standard output produced by the function while the function is in progress?).

If what you want is user code which runs *synchronously* when output goes to a particular stream that is easy with Gray or Gray-like streams.

### Concurrent handling of output

This requires threads (which, of course, may not give you true concurrency, but do in most implementations).  Here is how you might do it in one implementation: LispWorks.  Other implementations will have similar utilities and there may be portability shims.  Note this uses both multiprocessing and user-defined ('almost Gray') streams to define a stream which sends things into a mailbox.

```lisp
(defpackage :foo
  (:use :cl :stream :mp))

(in-package :foo)

(defclass mailbox-output-stream (fundamental-character-output-stream
                                 buffered-stream)
  ;; A character output stream which writes into a mailbox
  ((mailbox :initform (make-mailbox)
            :initarg :mailbox
            :reader mos-mailbox)
   (mailbox-limit :initform nil
                  :reader mos-limit))
  (:default-initargs
   :direction ':output))

(defmethod stream-write-buffer ((stream mailbox-output-stream)
                                buffer start end)
  ;; Write the buffer into the mailbox
  (let ((limit (mos-limit stream)))
    (if limit
        (mailbox-send-limited (mos-mailbox stream)
                              (subseq buffer start end)
                              limit)
      (mailbox-send (mos-mailbox stream)
                    (subseq buffer start end)))))

(defun call/supervising-output-stream (supervised supervisor)
  ;; Call SUPERVISED with an output stream whose mailbox SUPERVISOR is
  ;; watching.  Everything written into the mailbox will be a string,
  ;; until SUPERVISED returns, when T (normal return) or NIL (abnormal
  ;; return) will be written.  SUPERVISED runs in its own thread,
  ;; SUPERVISOR in this thread.  Return value is whatever SUPERVISOR
  ;; returns.  This pretty obviously should be wrapped in a macro.
  (let ((mbox (make-mailbox)))
    (funcall-async (lambda ()
                     (let ((okp nil))
                       (unwind-protect
                           (with-open-stream (o (make-instance 'mailbox-output-stream
                                                               :mailbox mbox))
                             (funcall supervised o)
                             (setf okp t))
                         (mailbox-send mbox okp)))))
    (funcall supervisor mbox)))

(defun trivial-printing-supervisor (mbox)
  ;; Just print everything we get from the mbox
  (do ((in (mailbox-read mbox) (mailbox-read mbox)))
      ((not (stringp in)) in)
    (print in)))

(defun collecting-supervisor (mbox)
  ;; Collect output from the mbox
  (loop for in = (mailbox-read mbox)
        while (stringp in)
        collect in into results
        finally (return (values results in))))
```

Then, for instance:

```lisp
> (call/supervising-output-stream
   (lambda (o)
     (let ((*standard-output* o))
       (compile-file "/tmp/foo.lisp")))
   #'collecting-supervisor)
(";;; Compiling file /tmp/foo.lisp ...
;;; Safety = 3, Speed = 1, Space = 1, Float = 1, Interruptible = 1
;;; Compilation speed = 1, Debug = 2, Fixnum safety = 3
;;; Source level debugging is on
;;; Source file recording is  on
;;; Cross referencing is on
; (lispworks:top-level-form 0)
; (defpackage \"FOO\")
; (lispworks:top-level-form 2)
; (defclass mailbox-output-stream)
; (method stream-write-buffer (mailbox-output-stream t t t))
; call/supervising-output-stream
; trivial-printing-supervisor
; collecting-supervisor
;; Processing Cross Reference Information")
t
```

### Synchronous handling of output

This requires Gray streams, or almost-gray streams or some other extensible stream API.  This is not part of the CL standard but I suspect all implementations have them.

Here is how you might do that, in LispWorks again.  First of all define a stream class which calls a bunch of handlers on buffer writes:

```
(defpackage :bar
  (:use :cl :stream))

(in-package :bar)

(defclass handling-output-stream (fundamental-character-output-stream
                                  buffered-stream)
  ;; A character output stream where buffer writes are handled by user
  ;; handlers.
  ((handlers :initform '()
             :initarg :handlers
             :accessor hos-handlers))
  (:default-initargs
   :direction ':output))

(defmethod stream-write-buffer ((stream handling-output-stream)
                                buffer start end)
  ;; Call the handlers
  (dolist (handler (hos-handlers stream))
    (funcall handler stream buffer start end)))
```

Now, as an example, here is a handler which will collect the written buffers into a secret list, which you can get access to, and another function which uses that handler.

```
(defun make-stream-hos-collector ()
  ;; Return a handler and a function which will return the list of
  ;; strings it is collecting
  (let ((collected '())
        (ct nil))
    (values (lambda (stream buffer start end)
              (declare (ignore stream))
              (let ((it (subseq buffer start end)))
                (if (not ct)
                    (setf collected (list it)
                          ct collected)
                  (setf (cdr ct) (list it)
                        ct (cdr ct)))))
            (lambda ()
              collected))))

(defun example ()
  (multiple-value-bind (handler returner) (make-stream-hos-collector)
    (with-open-stream (*standard-output* (make-instance 'handling-output-stream
                                                        :handlers (list handler)))
      (dotimes (i 10)
        (print i)
        (when (evenp i) (force-output))))
    (funcall returner))))
```

Calling `example` will then return something like this:

```
 > (example)
("
0 "
 "
1 
2 "
 "
3 
4 "
 "
5 
6 "
 "
7 
8 "
 "
9 ")
```

It's perfectly possible to capture each character, but catching buffer writes is generally a lot faster.

Comment: "this inherently requires multiple threads of control" no, it doesn't. nodejs can do it and it's single threaded. it does it with event notifications. I just have to remember how things were done in the 80s when using lisp.

Comment: node.js *doesn't* do this.  What it does is pass callbacks around, so no long-lived functions ever happen, all being well.  And If they do happen nothing else gets to happen while they're happening.  if you want event-driven programming in CL, ask about that, not something else.

Comment: it does do this. process.stdout.on('data', ...) will let you grab stdout in real time.

Comment: That's adding a handler for the stream.  That's trivial to do with Gray streams: see the current version of my answer for code which does that for LW (something similar is presumably possible for other implementations (you may need to implement your own buffered stream classes).